# Elixir variable is unsafe as it has been set inside a case/cond/receive

Tags: regex, elixir

I have this regex that is supposed to extract some named captures from a log line. If the first regex fails it is supposed to move to a second regex and try that instead. So basically this is my current code:

```
captures = Regex.named_captures(first_regex, log)
if captures == nil do
    captures = Regex.named_captures(backup_regex, log)
end
```

I'm using this method to avoid running two regexes if the first one is a match (sufficient in my scenario). This thing throws a warning stating that `the variable "captures" is unsafe as it has been set inside a case/cond/receive/if/&&/||. Please explicitly return the variable value instead.`

I could re-write it this way in order for it to stop throwing that warning:

```
captures = 
    case Regex.named_captures(squid_re, log) do
        nil -> Regex.named_captures(dante_re, log)
        {:username} -> # How do I return with username?
    end
```

..but, since it's my first day with elixir, I don't know how to assign that username to the `captures` variable. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this particular case, you can just use `||` since for `nil` (and `false`), `||` will return the value of the RHS, otherwise LHS:

```
captures = Regex.named_captures(first_regex, log) || Regex.named_captures(backup_regex, log)
```

If you really want to use `case`, this is how you'd do it:

```
captures = case Regex.named_captures(first_regex, log) do
  nil -> Regex.named_captures(backup_regex, log)
  captures -> captures
end
```

The second pattern will match any value and assign its value to `captures`, and you can just return the same value. I would suggest using `||` if the code is very similar to the one you posted though.

Comment: Yup...very elegant. I'll accept it in 8 minutes (timer)